# why my radio uncheck inside php?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
form#multiphase{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:24px; width:350px; }
form#multiphase > #phase2, #phase3, #show_all_data{ display:none; }
</style>
<script>
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function processPhase1(){
    if(document.form1.de.checked == true){
        _("phase1").style.display = "none";
        _("phase2").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert("i didt get the checked");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form1" id="multiphase">
    <div id="phase1">
    <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 1. </p>
                <label> I am whahaha. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="de" id="p2"value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 2. </p>
                <label> I am hehehe. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" id="p2"value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 12 -->
    <input type="button" value="Get Checked" onClick='processPhase1()'>
    </div>

    <div id="phase2">
    <input type="radio" name=button3>Box 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name=button4>Box 4
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Get Checked" onClick='processPhase2()'>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

why my check on php wont work ? my intention is when i check the 1st question radio and == checked , but it keep return me uncheck , can anyone tell me what wrong ? isit causing by my php code warp around the div ? how i going to by pass that i need that php warp also.

Comment: Show `print_r` or `var_dump` of your `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript code is causing the issue here.

Try this

```
_("phase1").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

instead of

```
_("phase1").style.display = "none";
```

The fields with `display:none` will not be sent to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
form#multiphase{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:24px; width:350px; }
form#multiphase > #phase2, #phase3, #show_all_data{ display:none; }
</style>
<script>
var checked = 0;
function changeChecked() {
    if (checked == 0){
    checked = 1;
    }else{
    checked = 0;
    }

}
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}


function processPhase1(){
    if(checked == 1){
        _("phase1").style.display = "none";
        _("phase2").style.display = "block";
        checked = 0
    } else {
        alert("i didt get the checked");
    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form1" id="multiphase">
    <div id="phase1">
    <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 1. </p>
                <label> I am whahaha. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="de" onchange="changeChecked()" id="p<?=$i?>" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?>  <?php } ?> </div>
                </div>

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 2. </p>
                <label> I am hehehe. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" onchange="changeChecked()" id="p3"value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 12 -->
    <input type="button" value="Get Checked" onClick='processPhase1()'>
    </div>

    <div id="phase2">
    <input type="radio" name=button3>Box 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name=button4>Box 4
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Get Checked" onClick='processPhase2()'>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry to confuse you with my question, actually it didt work , i dont want to get alert , i want to get the checked to be true , the demo isit working also , so mean once the 1 question be checked and i press continue , it will go to phare 2.

Comment: Well I think now is what you want, maybe not the best but the easiest way to reach your goal.